# Origin of the name Brahmin in fallout

Tags: terminology, fallout-series

[Brahmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmin) are a caste of religious teachers in Hinduism. Does the FO4 name for cows, Brahmin, have anything to do with this? I was thinking it's possible since Hinduism reveres cows.

Comment: What got this question the downvotes?

Comment: Quite likely the fact that the question is asking if the cows were deliberetly named. I interpret this as developer intent, and the fact that OP has confirmed an answer from leaked developer docs supports this. Developer intent is off topic, and we can't use the fact that this question has been answered with developer intent sourced as a weigh in.

Comment: FYI, the name started in the original Fallout, not FO4.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Brahmin of the Fallout universe are in fact descended from Indian Brahman cattle. This is covered in the *Fallout Bible 9*, one of a series of design docs from the Interplay days that were leaked when the studio was going under and Fallout seemed to be all but dead forever.

Chris Avellone:

> Brahmin are mutated brahmin cattle with two heads. If you just said, "hell, I thought brahmin were something from India," well, you'd be right. A bunch of brahmin made their way to the states long ago for crossbreeding purposes. When the bombs fell, brahmin grew two heads. They are quite hardy. They are also a delicious toasty brown, as you'll notice in the picture to the left. They attack by head-butting or trying to gore someone with their horns, so brahmin-tippers beware. For some reason, only the left-most brahmin head has horns, which raises some curious gender identity issues.

Read more [here](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Fallout_Bible_9&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop#Brahmin) and [here](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Brahmin)

Comment: Thank you for the useful links! That's a neat piece of lore.

Answer (score 0):

The game creators used that name because there is a breed of cattle in the U.S that is called Brahmin it was named after that religious caste. So indirectly yes it is related to that caste.

Comment: Do you perhaps have any proof of this? (It seems the most likely). And I do think the breed of cattle is called Brahman http://www.brahman.org/

Comment: Do note that brahman is also a term in Hinduism. The ultimate reality. Seems more likely the real life cows are named after this concept.